# Converting cURL into apache httpclient JAVA code

Tags: java, json, apache, curl

I have below curl command which I want to convert using Apache HTTPClient, can anyone help me with the code

curl -u "uname:Pass" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"  -d '{"browsers": [{"os": "Windows", "os_version": "7", "browser_version": "8.0", "browser": "ie"}], "url": "http://google.com"}' http://www.testingbrowse/test

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide us with the java code you have tried?

Comment: Was just trying but couldn’t get past :

httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, pass)); 
String s = http://google.com;
String posturl = "http://www.testingbrowse/test?url="+s+"&checkurl=0";
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(posturl);

Comment: could you please edit your post with a working snippets and tell the issue you see. How do you instantiate httpclient variable? Where do you provide the url,...

Answer (score 0):

```
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

try the below:

```
mpEntity.setContentType("application/json");
```

and the "curl -d":

```
 -d '{"metric":"proc.loadavg.15m"}'
```

You can use it:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); 
obj.put("metric", "proc.loadavg.15m");
```

But I think you need a array,you can change it to `JSONArray`

There is my question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863457/how-to-convert-curl-data-urlencode-to-httpclient